# Removing values in array without filter() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to remove specific (or any) values in dynamic array/range and return the result of the resized array without those values without using filter() as I need to use arrayformula.

For example,

> {"","","A","","B"} // size: 5

to

> {"A","B"} // size: 2

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might care to read [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/281264/1330560) from StackOverflow

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do this using a custom function. The array arrives in the function as an object containing (in general) a 2D array. This can be edited to delete the null strings, but that still leaves 'null' attributes in the object. JSON stringification allows final removal.

```
/*
 * Removes null elements from a two dimensional range.
 * The array is passed by Google sheets as an object containing a two dimensional array.
 */


function condense(as)
{
   for (r in as) { for (e in as[r] ) { if (as[r][e]===""){delete as[r][e];}}
                   if (as[r].every(function(e,i,a) {e===null;})){delete as[r];}
                 }
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(as).replace(/null,/g,"").replace(/,null]/g,"]"));
 }
```

Then:

=ARRAYFORMULA(condense({"","","A","","B"}))

Produces A and B in adjacent cells.

The function also works for general 2D ranges. For example

```
[["","",""],["","zero",""],["one","two",""],["three","four",""],["","",""]]
```

reduces to

```
[["zero"],["one","two"],["three","four"]]
```